# visit: command not found

Tags: software-installation

I just installed "visit", a scientific visualization software, on Ubuntu 12.04 using the commands given in the visit install notes for Unix given [here](http://portal.nersc.gov/svn/visit/trunk/releases/2.7.1/INSTALL_NOTES).  To be precise, my commands were entered from the directory I installed the .tar file and the install script (`/usr/Downloads`), and were

```
chmod 755 visit-install2_7_1 

./visit-install2_7_1 2.7.1 linux-x86_64-ubuntu11 ../Documents/visit

cd
echo "set path = ($path /Documents/visit/bin)" >> .cshrc
```

Now, when I enter the command "visit" in the CLI it produces the error "visit: command not found".  I'm not exactly a Linux guru, so what is the general fix for something like this?  If you'll notice in the commands above, the search path is set (I'm not really sure what this is); could this be the source of the problem?  I am only able to open the software by cd'ing to the `visit/bin` directory and running ./visit, which I don't think should be necessary.

Comment: Chances are you're using bash instead of c shell so exporting the path into .cshrc won't actually do anything.

Comment: @kalina The `visit-install2_7_1` executable is a bash file, is that what you mean?  I'm actually not sure what .cshrc is, it was just part of that command given in the install notes.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is likely with last line you followed in your instructions:

```
echo "set path = ($path /Documents/visit/bin)" >> .cshrc
```

This only applies if you're using C Shell. As a Ubuntu user the chances are that your default shell is bash.

Since you're getting a "command not found" error when trying to run your application, you can assume that your current $PATH variable doesn't include the folder `/Documents/visit/bin`. You can check this by running the following command:

```
echo $PATH
```

This will likely return something along the lines of:

```
/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games
```

To do the equivalent with bash you'll want to follow the instructions in this question over on Stack Overflow: [How to permanently set $PATH on Linux?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14637979/2632171)

Alternatively... follow these steps:

1. Edit `.bashrc` or `.profile` (in your home directory) with your favourite editor
2. Find a line that states `export PATH=`, if you find one, skip to step 4
3. Add a line at the bottom of the file that states `export PATH=$PATH`
4. Add `:<path/to>/visit/bin` to the end of the line you found in step 2, or added in step 3, where `<path/to>` is the folder you installed visit into

You only need to add this line in *either* `.bashrc` or `.profile`, there's no need to add it to both.

Comment: another option is to create a symlink.....

$> sudo ln -s /Documents/visit/bin/visit /usr/bin/

Comment: @WolfgangVogl that's a terrible idea...

Comment: why do you think @ Braiam - i've seen this in many cases - is there a reason to avoid?

Comment: @kalina I just used your alternate steps since the SO ones didn't seem to work and I'm still having the problem.  The command I entered in `.bashrc` is `export PATH=$PATH:/Documents/visit/bin`, is that correct?  The `export PATH=` wasn't in there originally so I added it.  Any thoughts?  Thanks for writing this up, by the way!

Comment: @bcf what is the full path to the `visit/bin` folder? Browse to the folder (so that running ./visit works) and then type `pwd` which will show you the present working directory - that is the path you need to export with path

Comment: @kalina Just did that but still same problem :/. After navigating to the folder so that `./visit` works and typing `pwd` I got `/home/kingdavid/Documents/visit/bin`, so my export line is now `export PATH=$PATH:/home/kingdavid/Documents/visit/bin`.

Comment: So now if you type `echo $PATH` do you see `:/home/kingdavid/Documents/visit/bin` on the end of the line that is echo'd? If not, you can either copy the entire `export` line out of the file you edited and run it, or log out and log back in again (since both .profile and .bashrc only execute when the shell first starts)

Comment: Hey!  It was indeed there, but I just had to restart the shell for it to work.  Thanks again for taking the time for helping me out!

Comment: @WolfgangVogl because it changes system wide /bin directory. Other users may have problems (even root).